# arabic keyboard backspace issue android

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic, backspace

I have an edit text and when I write Arabic text inside it and select any other view and get back to my edit text and try to use backspace key, text not deleted and I can't move the cursor in my text

can anyone help please ?